# How to add blogs in magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2.2.6, blog

How to add blogs in admin magento 2.2.6. because i can't see blog menu section in admin. please let me know.

Comment: By default magento is not provide blog functionality you have to install blog extension find it [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=blog#q=blog&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_all_editions%5D%5B0%5D=Community&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%202&nR%5Bprice.USD.default%5D%5B%3C%3D%5D%5B0%5D=0&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1)

Comment: did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

There is free blog module already check this --

> https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-blog

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I put blog file by filezila. but extention not installed.

Comment: please check screenshot i cant able to enable this extention  "http://prntscr.com/lam3wr" . http://prntscr.com/lam4l3 please let me know issue?

Comment: are you trying to install new fresh magento2 ?

Comment: yes "http://www.gsmalhi.com/wedding/" this is my site link.

Comment: your screenshot shows that your server is missing required extension for magento2. you need to install all of them. check this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html)

Comment: your site is in infinite loop, could not open.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to add blog feature in the Magento store:

1. **Create a custom module**, in which you can add the features which you like and ignore the features which you don't want.
2. **Integrate WordPress with Magento 2:** If you want to manage content from the WordPress backend, but want to integrate the frontend of the blog like Magento, you can consider integrating WordPress with your Magento 2 store. For more info, have a look at https://www.wpblog.com/magento-2-wordpress-integration/.
3. **Install a blog extension for Magento 2**: There are many free and paid modules available for the blog in Magento 2. Few of the links are below:

   https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-blog-extension/
   https://marketplace.magento.com/magefan-module-blog.html (Personally my favorite)
   https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-2-extensions/blog (paid module)
   https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/blog.html

Comment: i put bolg module by filezile. but i can't check in admin.

Comment: please check screenshot i cant able to enable this extention  "http://prntscr.com/lam3wr" . http://prntscr.com/lam4l3 please let me know issue?

Comment: @neharani, for installation instructions of magefan blog module, please follow https://magefan.com/blog/magneto2-blog-extension-installation/